# Magento 2 - Moving site - 'No such entity'

Tags: magento2, database, reindex

After I moved a site from staging.site.nl to site.nl I received a weird error. If I try to reindex the site I get this error: `No such entity.`

If I try to login I get this message:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:15:"No such entity.";i:1;s:5964:"#0 /home/site/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Store.php(542): Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteRepository->getById('0')
```

I copied all files, moved the database and did replace the URL values in core_config_data.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same issue. It appeared to be caused by some Entity IDs that needed to be set to 0.

> When you transfer the data the insert records on these specific records are automatically generated and tend to start at 1 and not 0.

This script worked for me:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Absolute life saver!!!!! Remember now having a similar issue in Magento 1 a few years back.

Comment: Magento and it's ridiculous nuances are enough to drive anyone crazy! Thanks for this!

Comment: this code is not helping me,is there is any way that can track exactly what entity is missing?

Comment: Sorry @akgola, I have bee out of the Magento world now for a few years since this was answered, so not sure on that.

Comment: @AdamStacey, Its not working for me. even i used above solution

Answer (score 1):

I changed database connection in env.php and the changed DB had everything like Adam's answer, but, due to wrong configuration in env.php, it could not connect to store_website table. I missed to write the table prefix there. After correcting, *deploy* and cache *flush* fixed that error.

Comment: Thanks. I helped me in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a bad export of my database. Everything seems to be fine, but after I did a dump via command line instead of Querious everything started to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've fix that adding default set:

```
INSERT INTO `YOUR_DB`.`eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_name`, `sort_order`) VALUES ('1', '1', 'Default', '1');
INSERT INTO `YOUR_DB`.`eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_name`, `sort_order`) VALUES ('2', '2', 'Default', '1');
INSERT INTO `YOUR_DB`.`eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_name`, `sort_order`) VALUES ('3', '3', 'Default', '1');
INSERT INTO `YOUR_DB`.`eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_name`, `sort_order`) VALUES ('4', '4', 'Default', '1');
INSERT INTO `YOUR_DB`.`eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_name`, `sort_order`) VALUES ('5', '5', 'Default', '1');
INSERT INTO `YOUR_DB`.`eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_name`, `sort_order`) VALUES ('6', '6', 'Default', '1');
INSERT INTO `YOUR_DB`.`eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_name`, `sort_order`) VALUES ('7', '7', 'Default', '1');
INSERT INTO `YOUR_DB`.`eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_set_name`, `sort_order`) VALUES ('8', '8', 'Default', '1');
```

But now I should fix product name as it's missing.