# Magento 2 reindex returns No such entity

Tags: magento2, reindex, magento-2.0, migration

I have successfully migrated the catalog from Magento 1.9.2.3 to Magento 2.0.2.
After the migration, I did reindex using the command `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`.

All is reindexed successfully, except indexes `catalog_category_product` and `catalog_product_category`, returning `No such entity.` in shell and notification `Reindex Required` in admin.
I've checked `var/log/` but no errors.

As a result, products are added to categories in the backend but categories show up empty on the frontend.

What might cause this problem?
How can I debug?

Comment: basically the same http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102739/magento-2-moving-site-no-such-entity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to Raphael:

I Debugged this code with altering the exception constructor for debug purposes (either by xdebug or old dumps).
Alter the construct of the exception for now (the file is `\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException.php`)

```
$trace = debug_backtrace();
var_dump($trace[1]['class'] . '::' . $trace[1]['function'] . '('.$trace[1]['line'] .')';
die();
```

After that go up one stack and check the arguments given (the args are also available in the debug backtrace, but dumping magento objects isn't really browser friendly).

Came to the conclusion, that it was in the `storeGroupRepository` where it couldn't find the group id. Dived into the store tables and saw a few lines in the store table that were referencing a `store_group` that wasn't in the `store_group` table(store group not exist in relevant table).

Removed the faulty store lines and the error has been gone ever since.

But, keep in mind that it can also be in a different table/other reason. for example website, store itself or store group in this case. So that is always a little search you have to perform yourself.

Also found out that there were quite a lot of references to these stores and also removed them manually in the db. This can be a tedious work but it will solve the problem.

And don't forget to remove your hacks.

Comment: why don't you use xdebug instead?

Comment: @TimVroom I have also same error.Please help me   https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/236187/24878

Answer (score 15):

Not sure if this is too late to add, but when I had this It appeared to be caused by some entity ids that needed to be set to 0.

This script worked for me:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this helped me a lot, thank you for sharing!

Comment: This also worked for me :)

Answer (score 4):

Ok so the `No such entity.` error message comes from `\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException.php`.

This class is a custom exception class of Magento and it is used a lot in Magento 2.

Whenever you see code like:

```
catch (NoSuchEntityException $e)
```

Or

```
throw NoSuchEntityException;
```

This class is being used.

The problem in your case is that it's hard to find out from where that exception is being thrown.

So to narrow it a bit, you can start debugging the two classes related to your indexes that fail:

- `Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product` => **catalog_category_product** index
- `Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Category` => **catalog_product_category** index

Fortunately, the second one extends the first one so you've got one starting point.

You've got to keep in mind that each of this indexer class uses action rows classes to process the reindexing:

- `Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Category\Action\Rows`
- `Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Rows`

To me that's where you should start debugging as those action row classes are the direct classes which are reindexing those two indexes.

I really hope it will help you find your problem.

Comment: Hi @Raphael , I have similar issue for customer creation after migration.Please help me   https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/236187/24878

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same

[Magento 2 - Moving site - 'No such entity'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102739/magento-2-moving-site-no-such-entity)

`cd /magento-root-path/var`

`rm -rf *`

`cd ../`

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`rm -rf ./var/di`

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

`chown -R www-data` .

Answer (score 0):

THIS WORKED FOR ME AFTER TRYING EVERYTHING.

Assuming your site is in `Developer Mode`, you can change it to `Production Mode` and clear/flush cache and then switch back to `Developer Mode`.

I had this issue in the front end, as i recently moved the database from one server to another. I have managed to solve by this way.

HOPE THIS HELPS SOME ONE.

Answer (score 0):

This error, in my case, was for a multi-store, multi-domain setup. Magento truncates store codes. If you're mapping domains to store codes go make sure the store code matches the routing specified in index.php ( or wherever you map ). In the admin check under ***"Stores"*** > "***All Stores***." Check your website, store & store view store codes.

Once I realized Magento truncated the store code I'd entered and made the same adjustment in mapping & everything started working again.