# After Migration from Magento 1.9.1.0 to Magento 2.2.4, Customer Creation Issue

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration-tool

I have Migrated website Magento 1.9.1.0 to Magento 2.2.4 successfully by Using Magento Data Migration Tool. My Old Magento Website was multi-store/website. Everything is working fine but when I am going to create an account then I am getting below errors

**No such entity test with email = test999@mail.com, websiteId = 1**

I have tried to some fixes by running below command but this is already updated

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE store SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE store_group SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE store_website SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

While I have tried to create account programatically,its creating successfully but email id is not inserting in **customer_entity** table while it inserting in **customer_entity_varchar** table.

After migrating data ,website id and store id are same for both Magento and Magento2.I am also able to create product as well as place order is also working.

Is there is any option to check which entity id is missing when save customer?

I have a lot of research but nothing found to resolve this issue. Please help me.

Comment: Did you try reindex after migration?

Comment: Yes,Many times.

Comment: @akgola may i  know what tutorial you following to upgrade from Magento 1 to 2?

Comment: @Gem,I have followed tutorial https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-install.html along with stackexchange forum search.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have resolved that issue with help of Magento guy @victor-v-rad

by comparing attribute_code "email" in the eav_attribute table with Magento default and found that backend type was "varchar" after migration while it is "static" in Magento Default. After updating it is working now fine.

full discussion here:

https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool/issues/565#issuecomment-409515576

Comment: hi @akgola, I checked in eav_attribute table, have value backend_type as static only, still i am getting error like "No such entity with customerId =  [] []"

Comment: @jafarpinjar let me know more detail about issue so that I can help you.

Comment: hi @akgola, here i have posted the issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250848/can-not-login-with-customer-emai-in-magento2

Comment: did you compare all attribute(column type,name.....) from eav_attribute after migration with default magento 2.if not please compare.