# Magento 2 Aftet Migration Error - Reindex No Such Entity Error

Tags: database, migration, reindex, magento2.3.4

```
[root@test]# php bin/magento indexer:reindex
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Flat Data index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:46
No such entity.
No such entity.
No such entity.
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:14
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:05
```

Any help thanks.

Comment: Instead of changing the question, you can always `update` the question with more details. So in case if someone has posted an answer related to earlier query make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED:
There was store on 'stores' table that was relating with an 'store_group' that wasn´t there. Changed the ID and reindex worked fine.

Note : remove values from the table design_change

Comment: Hi@zus, can you explain above process.In my case there is no value in design_change table.

Answer (score 1):

When the allocated memory size for a temporary table will be greater than 20% of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, the error message is written to the Magento log.

Can you please update the value for **batchRowsCount** to 10000 in `Vendor_Module/etc/di.xml` file of **catalog_category_product** (Category Products) indexer.

For more details related to `Exceeding allocated memory size`  issue read Magento official document [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/indexer-batch.html#exceeding-allocated-memory-size).

For instance:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="batchRowsCount" xsi:type="number">10000</argument>
        <argument name="batchSizeManagement" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\CategoryProductBatchSize</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Where is located vendor_module/etc/di.xml

Comment: The default config file resides at `Magento/Catalog/etc/di.xml` for the configured object `Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Product\Action\Full`.

Comment: Yes, I updated batch size 1000 then run reindex command still getting error no such entity error. Anything else I need to update?

Comment: Try running the `php bin/magento s:di:c` compilation command and then run the reindex command again and check.

Comment: Yes, I run this command, still my issue retain.

Comment: Can you try `bin/magento indexer:reset` and then  `bin/magento indexer:reindex` ? And also check this post: 1. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/106793/magento-2-reindex-returns-no-such-entity and 2. https://mage2-blog.com/magento-2-indexer-returns-no-such-entity/

Comment: Yes I did,  `bin/magento indexer:reset` and then  `bin/magento indexer:reindex`   let me check your links.

Comment: Is my path right : /app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/di.xml and my code : https://justpaste.it/1t6ag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110689/discussion-between-zus-and-bhaumik-upadhyay).

Comment: @zus Messaged on chat.

Comment: @zus Does the solution work for you?

Comment: No, still searching madly.

Comment: Any solution found?