# Magento 2 admin not working after migration

Tags: magento2, admin, migration

We have developed a dev website having URL like dev.abc.com and it has magento 2 installed and it is working fine.

Now I need to migrate it on another domain say test.abc.com for that I have done following steps:

1. Dump for the website which is running for `dev.abc.com`.
2. Rename the URL from `http://dev.abc.com` to `test.abc.com`.
3. Deleted var/cache folder
4. Change the permission for var and pub folder
5. Change the database credentials in app/etc/env.php

After that Front end section is working fine but admin page is blank and not opening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 - Moving site - 'No such entity'](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102739/magento-2-moving-site-no-such-entity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is resolved by this query :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for these tables in the database it fixed my problem after remove/replace the static domains in the ***core_config_data*** Table

```
web/secure/base_url

web/secure/base_link_url

web/secure/base_skin_url

web/secure/base_media_url
```

Look what the values are in there and change them accordingly

Comment: I have done this as well but still not working for me :(

Comment: what does your .htaccess look like?

Comment: http://go.sparkpostmail.com/f/a/5NCGJYAfvlXHrg_Fn0ACDg~~/AABzJwA~/RgRZFdFoP0EIAWuZI94kdX1XA3NwY1gEAAAAAFkIaXBfcG9vbDFCCgAFaEwzV1Zy99pSGmNoZXRhbi50aXdhcmlAZGlhc3BhcmsuY29tCVEEAAAAAEQ_aHR0cDovL2ptcC5zaC9lL0tXUjY2akpHTlN6UmNiczhXV2RVP3VyaT12LzQ5aUF2R2Eyb2haSDdMajZEdUtYRwJ7fQ~~

Comment: i hope its on the server only as .htaccess

Comment: yes it is uploaded as .htaccess on server

Comment: My last try Just Open the

MAGENTO_ROOT/app/etc/di.xml

and replace below code form line number 574

<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>

TO

<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>

Comment: Still not working for me :(

Comment: Did you re do all your steps once ? It seems like there is another issue

Comment: I have tried all step once again but it still shows same error
 http://jmp.sh/0Aq1OSE

Comment: Anybody has answer for this ? I need to fix this ASAP

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102739/magento-2-moving-site-no-such-entity

Comment: I have also done database migration with command prompt

Comment: Anyone has answer for this I am still stuck on this :(

Answer (score 0):

If your magento2 install is running under a different domain than your source site (eg. when importing a live website into a local dev version), your cookie domain is probably wrong. In the core_config_data table, look for the `web/cookie/cookie_domain` key and set the value to match your local domain.

Don't forget to run `bin/magento cache:flush` after updating the config value.